# Perl Extracting Text

Tags: regex, perl, search

I have been working on this for so long!
I'd appreciate your help...

What my doc will look like:

```
<text>
<text> command <+>= "stuff_i_need" <text>
<text>
<text> command <+>= stuff <text>
<text>
<text> command <+>= -stuff <text>
<text>
```

- Anything with tangle brackets around it is optional
- stuff could be anything (apple, orange, banana) but it is what I need to extract
- the command is fixed

My code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Diff;

# File Handlers 
open(my $ofh, '>in.txt');
open(my $ifh, '<out.txt');

while (<$ifh>)
{
    # Read in a line
    my $line = $_;
    chomp $line;

    # Extract stuff
    my $extraction = $line;

    if ($line =~ /command \+= /i) {        
        $extraction =~ s/.*"(.*)".*/$1/;
        # Write to file
        print $ofh "$extraction\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to specify what operators are valid. In your code you look only for `+=`, but in your sample input you have both `+=` and `=`. The same goes for `command` vs `command2`. You need to specify the exact conditions when you want to extract the word.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @TLP. I have made some changes, please let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example input:

```
 if ($line =~ /command\d*\s*\+?=\s*["-]?(\w+)"?/i) {    
    $extraction = $1; 
    print "$extraction\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. For extraction, don't use substitution (i.e., use `m//` and not `s///`). If you use a match, the parenthetical groups inside the match will be returned as a list (and assigned to `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. if you prefer).
2. The `=~` binds the variable you want to match. So you want `$extraction` to actually be `$line`.
3. Your `.*` match is too greedy and will prevent the match from succeeding the way you want. What I mean by "greedy" is that `.*` will match the trailing `"` in your lines. It will consume the rest of the input on the line and then try match that `"` and fail because you've reached the end of the line.

You want to specify what the word could be. For example, if it's letters, then match `[a-zA-Z]`

```
my ($extraction) = $line =~ /command \+= "([a-zA-Z]*)"/;
```

If it's a number, you want `[0-9]`:

```
my ($extraction) = $line =~ /command \+= "([0-9]*)"/;
```

If it could be anything except `"`, use `[^"]`, which means "anything but `"`":

```
my ($extraction) = $line =~ /command \+= "([^"]*)"/;
```

It usually helps to try to match against just what you are looking for rather than the blanket `.*`.

Comment: Based on the sample input, quotes are not required around the matched word.

Comment: No, they're not, but I'm trying to fix just one thing at a time. If he can get one working match, he can start tweaking and work outward from there. There are too many problems in this question to deal with all of them in any one answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The following regular expression would help you:

```
m{
    (?<= = )        # Find an `=`
    \s*             # Match 0 or more whitespaces
    (?:             # Do not capture
        [ " \- ]    # Match either a `"` or a `-`
    )?              # Match once or never
    (               # Capture
        [^ " \s ]+  # Match anything but a `"` or a whitespace
    )
}x;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following one-liner will extract a word (a sequence of characters without spaces) that follows an equal sign prefixed by an optional plus sign, surrounded by optional quotes. It will read from `in.txt` and write to `out.txt`.

```
perl -lne 'push @a, $1 if /command\s*\+?=\s*("?\S+"?)/ }{ 
    print for @a' in.txt > out.txt
```

The full code - if you prefer script form - is:

```
BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    push @a, $1 if /command\s*\+?=\s*("?\S+"?)/;
}
{
    print $_ foreach (@a);
}
```

Courtesy of the Deparse function of [the O module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?O).

Answer (score 0):

A light solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $ifh, '<','in.txt';
open my $ofh, '>', 'out.txt';

while (<$ifh>)
{
    if (/
        \s command\s\+?=\s
        (?:-|("))?     # The word can be preceded by an optional - or "
        (\w+)
        (?(1)\1)\s+    # If the word is preceded by a " it must be end 
                       # with a "
        /x)
    {
        print $ofh $2."\n";
    }
}
```